# Black Duck fails to run gradlew dependencies successfully

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

Since upgrading from Gradle 6.7.1 to 7.0 (which may be a red herring), [Black Duck](https://www.synopsys.com/software-integrity/security-testing/software-composition-analysis.html) scans of my Gradle project now fail.

Here is the error message:

```
* Where:
Initialization script '/root/blackduck/runs/2022-01-18-19-06-00-216/shared/gradle/init-detect.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dependencies'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.internal.dependencies.AsciiDependencyReportRenderer.startProject() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated) values: [root project '<redacted>']
  Possible solutions: startProject(org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.internal.ProjectDetails), startProject(org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.internal.ProjectDetails)
```

Builds are successful when the Gradle build is run without Black Duck.

The Black Duck scan is run with the following command:

```
bash detect.sh --blackduck.url=<redacted> --blackduck.trust.cert=true --blackduck.api.token=<redacted> --detect.project.name=<redacted> --detect.project.version.name=Developer --detect.source.path=.
```

Here is my full `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://<redacted>/nexus/repository/maven-central"
    }
    maven {
      url "https://<redacted>/nexus/repository/thirdparty"
    }
    maven {
      url "https://<redacted>/nexus/repository/gradle-plugins"
    }
  }
}

plugins {
  id "java"
}

def nexusUsername = (System.getenv("NEXUS_USERNAME") != null ? System.getenv("NEXUS_USERNAME") : (project.hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? "$NEXUS_USERNAME" : ""))
def nexusPassword = (System.getenv("NEXUS_PASSWORD") != null ? System.getenv("NEXUS_PASSWORD") : (project.hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? "$NEXUS_PASSWORD" : ""))

repositories {}

ext {}

dependencies {}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
  }
}
```

My ideas for what could be wrong:

- There is a bug in the auto-generated `/root/blackduck/runs/2022-01-18-19-06-00-216/shared/gradle/init-detect.gradle` file (maybe Black Duck doesn't play nice with Gradle 7.0)
- I run the `detect.sh` script with the wrong arguments
- There is something wrong with my `build.gradle` file

I am looking for any suggestions on how to solve this problem so that my Black Duck scans can run successfully once more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was I was using an older version of the Black Duck `detect.sh` script. I was using version 6.9.1. Once I upgraded to using version 7.6.0, the Black Duck scan worked once more.

To use the new version of the script, you can do the following (note the `detect7.sh` in the URL; if you download plain `detect.sh` you will get an old version):

```sh
curl --fail https://detect.synopsys.com/detect7.sh -o detect.sh
export DETECT_LATEST_RELEASE_VERSION=7.6.0
bash detect.sh <args>
```

Comment: Made my day. Thx.
Was using the default Synopsis instructions and `curl https://detect.synopsys.com/detect.sh` downloads an older version.

Comment: The same issue arises employing Jenkins [Synopsis Detect](https://plugins.jenkins.io/blackduck-detect/) plugin <7.0.0.